# Keras validation accuracy is increasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

*Updated : increased rotate range to 180, added GaussianNoise. see codes*

I am using CNN for image classification. I have 2 class 3500 gray scaled photo of each in training dataset and 1000 of each in validation data set. The problem is first 5-10 epochs train acc and valid acc is increasing but then valid acc is starting to decrease so sharp while train acc keeps increasing.

[Old Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuhIW.png)
[image]

I saw that its because overfitting but I also tried to deal with overfitting with putting some parameters in `ImageDataGenerator.`

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                           rotation_range=180,
                                           width_shift_range=.15,
                                           height_shift_range=.15,
                                           horizontal_flip=True,
                                           fill_mode='nearest',
                                           shear_range=0.05,
                                           zoom_range=0.5
                                           )
```

Also I put `Dropout` layers in CNN architecture.

```
model = Sequential([
    GaussianNoise(0.01, input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1)),
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1)),
    Dropout(0.7),
    MaxPooling2D(),

    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.7),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.5),

    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.7),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.5),

    Flatten(),
    Dropout(0.7),

    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

I have set up Learning rate:

```
adamOpti = Adam(lr=0.00005)
model.compile(optimizer=adamOpti,
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Even I have set up EarlyStopping too:

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=200)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

TL,DR List of what I tried for deal overfitting:

1. Image Augmentation
2. Reduce number of layers and neurons
3. Shuffle train image generator
4. Dropouts
5. Early Stopping
6. Tune learning rate
7. More data (still collecting dunno until when)

I dont know is there anything left that I missed up. All comments are welcome.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It definitely look like overfitting, have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139980/prevention-of-overfitting-in-convolutional-layers-of-a-cnn

Comment: as you can see i tried most of all suggestions such as dropout, make network smaller, augmentation etc. Now I am trying to bring more data to see if will there any difference.

Comment: you'r overfitting. you can try to reduce your CNN complexity; e.g reducing number of layer or number of neurones. Also check that training and validation set have been splited with a random way

Comment: thank you for comment. I reduced number of layers and neurons as well but still got almost same output. I forgot to add but also shuffle=True in train and valid image generators.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with an image augmentation process.  Add blur, rotate, noise, clipping, etc to your images such that the model isn't seeing the same set of images over and over.  As counter intuitive as it may feel, you need to make it harder on your model by adding variety.  This will allow it to generalize better.

Also make sure that your classes are not highly imbalanced (no more than 10x the number of images in your biggest class vs the smallest one).  This is to make sure you don't have one class over-represented in your batches.  If you have way more images in one class vs the other, either delete some from the bigger class, or gather more for the smaller classes (or generate new ones that are augmented in some way) until you have a more even number of images per class.

Lastly you can increase your batch size if your hardware will support it, so that it increases the diversity of images per batch.

Edit:

It looks like you only have two classes, and they are balanced.  I would suggest trying image augmentation as the first approach (rotate, blur, noise, clip, skew)

Comment: Thank you for comment but are you sure that I am not augmenting images? Because as you can see in codes there is rotation, zoom, clip in ImageDataGenerator. am I mssing something here?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, try creating a very wide range for those parameters, so that rotation can be between -180, 180 for example, and add noise, blur, and other distortions way more than you think you should  Hopefully the model struggles to fit and you see increasing accuracy over many epochs.  If this is the case you can tune those back a bit until you find the right balance!

Comment: thank you for all suggestions. I increased rotation range but I cant add noise and blur since my images are already noised and blurred too much :( The thing that makes me confuse is this model was working before I put more data. Is decaresing number of data can be solution? (what a weird question ahaha)

Comment: There is a good chance you can build a quality model of way fewer images than you think.  It's usually an issue of variety not quantity.  Don't let yourself be afraid to add blur and noise, even though you think it's a bad idea - confirm it for yourself by experimentation.  You will learn something from it either way.

Comment: I just completed an experiment by new model that configurated with your suggestions. Val acc remains same :/ Updated results and code. I think I am doing something wrong but what