# Inconsistent OCR Results: Different Predictions during Training and Testing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm encountering an issue with my custom OCR (Optical Character Recognition) model where it produces different predictions during training and testing phases.

During training, the model seems to perform really well, unimaginably well, achieving high accuracy on the training dataset. However, when I use the model to predict text from images during testing, the results are inconsistent. The confidence scores for each class also seem to fluctuate significantly, leading to unexpected predictions.

```
Training started...
Epoch [1/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 1.4840
Epoch [2/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.1713
Epoch [3/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.1087
Epoch [4/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0793
Epoch [5/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0793
Epoch [6/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0552
Epoch [7/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0501
Epoch [8/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0484
Epoch [9/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0595
Epoch [10/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0437
Epoch [11/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0351
Epoch [12/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0914
Epoch [13/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0304
Epoch [14/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0406
Epoch [15/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0315
Epoch [16/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0331
Epoch [17/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0220
Epoch [18/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0238
Epoch [19/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0272
Epoch [20/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0259
Epoch [21/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0210
Epoch [22/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0826
Epoch [23/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0673
Epoch [24/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0240
Epoch [25/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0198
Epoch [26/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0250
Epoch [27/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0203
Epoch [28/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0170
Epoch [29/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0204
Epoch [30/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0177
Epoch [31/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0208
Epoch [32/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0231
Epoch [33/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0156
Epoch [34/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0117
Epoch [35/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0171
Epoch [36/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0138
Epoch [37/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0196
Epoch [38/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0158
Epoch [39/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0183
Epoch [40/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0163
Epoch [41/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0305
Epoch [42/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0504
Epoch [43/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0404
Epoch [44/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0176
Epoch [45/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0140
Epoch [46/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0099
Epoch [47/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0123
Epoch [48/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0121
Epoch [49/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0118
Epoch [50/50], Step [100/133], Loss: 0.0140
Training finished.
Testing started...
Predicted: A, Actual: A, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: B, Actual: B, Confidence: 98.97%
Predicted: C, Actual: C, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: D, Actual: D, Confidence: 99.46%
Predicted: E, Actual: E, Confidence: 99.63%
Predicted: F, Actual: F, Confidence: 99.32%
Predicted: G, Actual: G, Confidence: 99.92%
Predicted: H, Actual: H, Confidence: 99.99%
Predicted: I, Actual: I, Confidence: 90.64%
Predicted: J, Actual: J, Confidence: 97.04%
Predicted: K, Actual: K, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: L, Actual: L, Confidence: 99.08%
Predicted: M, Actual: M, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: O, Actual: A, Confidence: 67.16%
Predicted: P, Actual: P, Confidence: 96.75%
Predicted: Q, Actual: Q, Confidence: 99.71%
Predicted: R, Actual: R, Confidence: 99.98%
Predicted: S, Actual: S, Confidence: 99.25%
Predicted: T, Actual: T, Confidence: 91.48%
Predicted: U, Actual: U, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: V, Actual: V, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: W, Actual: W, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: X, Actual: X, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: Y, Actual: Y, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: Z, Actual: Z, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 0, Actual: 0, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 1, Actual: 1, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 2, Actual: 2, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 3, Actual: 3, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 4, Actual: 4, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 5, Actual: 5, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 6, Actual: 6, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 7, Actual: 7, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 8, Actual: 8, Confidence: 100.00%
Predicted: 9, Actual: 9, Confidence: 100.00%
Accuracy on test dataset: 99.69%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've developed a custom OCR model using PyTorch. Here's a brief overview of the relevant components:

- OCRModel: Defines the architecture of the OCR neural network.
- OCRDataset: Custom dataset class to handle OCR data loading and preprocessing.
- OCRHandler: Handles training and testing of the OCR model.
- OCR: Inherits from OCRHandler, provides additional functionality for image-to-text conversion.

During testing, the model produces different predictions than expected. For instance, the model might predict different characters or provide low confidence scores for correct predictions. I expected the model to produce consistent and accurate predictions during both training and testing phases, maintaining high confidence scores for correct predictions. I'm not sure what to do now, I have minimal knowledge in neural networks.

```py
import string
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError, Image
from typing import Optional, Union


class OCRModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int):
        """
        Initialize the OCRModel.

        Args:
            num_classes (int): Number of classes for classification.
        """
        super(OCRModel, self).__init__()
        # Define convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        # Define pooling layer
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # Define fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 16 * 16, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        Forward pass through the network.

        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor.

        Returns:
            torch.Tensor: Output tensor.
        """
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


class OCRDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path: Union[str, Path], transform: Optional[transforms.Compose] = None):
        """
        Initialize the OCRDataset.

        Args:
            data_path (Union[str, Path]): Path to the dataset.
            transform (Optional[transforms.Compose]): Transformations to apply to the data.
        """
        if not isinstance(data_path, (str, Path)):
            raise TypeError("data_path must be a string or a Path object.")
        self.data_path = Path(data_path)
        self.transform = transform
        self.dataset = ImageFolder(root=str(self.data_path), transform=transform)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[None, None]:
        while True:
            try:
                image, label = self.dataset[idx]
                # Convert image to PIL Image to handle errors
                image = transforms.ToPILImage()(image)
                if self.transform:
                    image = self.transform(image)
                break
            except (UnidentifiedImageError, OSError) as error:
                print(f"Error opening image at index {idx}: {error}")
                idx += 1
                if idx >= len(self):
                    print("Reached end of dataset.")
                    return None, None
        return image, label


class OCRHandler:
    def __init__(self, model: OCRModel):
        """
        Initialize the OCRHandler.

        Args:
            model (OCRModel): OCR model instance.
        """
        if not isinstance(model, OCRModel):
            raise TypeError("model must be an instance of OCRModel.")
        self.model = model

    def train(self, train_data_path: Union[str, Path], num_epochs: int = 10, batch_size: int = 32,
              learning_rate: float = 0.001) -> None:
        """
        Train the OCR model.

        Args:
            train_data_path (Union[str, Path]): Path to the training dataset.
            num_epochs (int): Number of epochs for training.
            batch_size (int): Batch size for training.
            learning_rate (float): Learning rate for optimization.
        """
        # Print a message to indicate the start of training
        print("Training started...")

        # Prepare the training dataset with transformations
        train_dataset = OCRDataset(train_data_path, transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((64, 64)),
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ]))

        # Create a data loader for the training dataset
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

        # Define loss criterion and optimizer
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

        # Loop through epochs
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            # Initialize running loss for each epoch
            running_loss = 0.0
            # Loop through batches in the training dataloader
            for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
                # Clear previous gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                # Forward pass
                outputs = self.model(images)
                # Calculate loss
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                # Backpropagation
                loss.backward()
                # Update weights
                optimizer.step()
                # Accumulate loss
                running_loss += loss.item()
                # Print loss statistics every 100 steps
                if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
                    print(
                        f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Step [{i + 1}/{len(train_dataloader)}], Loss: {running_loss / 100:.4f}")
                    running_loss = 0.0
        print("Training finished.")

    def test(self, testing_path: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
        """
        Test the OCR model on the test dataset.

        Args:
            testing_path (str): Path to the test dataset.
        """
        # Print a message to indicate testing has started
        print("Testing started...")

        # Prepare the test dataset
        test_dataset = ImageFolder(root=str(testing_path), transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((64, 64)),
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ]))

        # Create a data loader for the test dataset
        test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

        # Initialize counters for correct predictions and total samples
        correct = 0
        total = 0

        # Disable gradient calculation for inference
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Iterate over the test dataset
            for images, labels in test_dataloader:
                # Forward pass through the model
                outputs = self.model(images)
                # Get the predicted classes
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                # Update correct predictions count
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
                # Update total count
                total += labels.size(0)
                # Calculate confidence of the prediction
                confidence = torch.softmax(outputs, 1)[0][predicted.item()].item() * 100
                # Convert predicted and actual labels to uppercase letters or digits
                predicted_label = string.ascii_uppercase[predicted.item()] if predicted.item() < 26 else str(
                    predicted.item() - 26)
                actual_label = string.ascii_uppercase[labels.item()] if labels.item() < 26 else str(labels.item() - 26)
                # Print prediction details
                print(f"Predicted: {predicted_label}, Actual: {actual_label}, Confidence: {confidence:.2f}%")

        # Calculate and print accuracy
        print(f"Accuracy on test dataset: {(correct / total) * 100:.2f}%")

    def save(self) -> None:
        """
        Save the trained model.
        """
        save_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
        save_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        model_path = save_path / "ocr_model.pt"
        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), model_path)
        print(f"Model saved successfully at: {model_path}")


class OCR(OCRHandler):
    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        """
        Initialize the OCR class.

        Args:
            debug (bool, optional): Whether to enable debug mode. Defaults to False.
        """
        # Load the OCR model
        ocr_model = OCRModel(num_classes=36)
        super().__init__(ocr_model)
        self.debug = debug

    def image_to_text(self, image_path: Union[str, Path]) -> Union[str, tuple[str, dict | None]]:
        """
        Convert an image to text using the OCR model.

        Args:
            image_path (Union[str, Path]): Path to the input image.

        Returns:
            Union[str, tuple[str, dict]]: The predicted text. If debug mode is enabled,
                returns a tuple containing the predicted text and a dictionary with debug information.
        """
        # Prepare the input image
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((64, 64)),
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ])
        # Add batch dimension
        image = transform(image).unsqueeze(0)

        # Disable gradient calculation for inference
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Forward pass through the model
            outputs = self.model(image)
            # Get the predicted class
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            # Convert predicted label to uppercase letter or digit
            predicted_text = string.ascii_uppercase[predicted.item()] if predicted.item() < 26 else str(
                predicted.item() - 26)

            if self.debug:
                # Calculate confidence scores
                confidence_scores = torch.softmax(outputs, 1)[0].tolist()
                # Convert confidence scores to percentages
                confidence_percentages = [score * 100 for score in confidence_scores]
                # Create a dictionary with debug information
                debug_info = {
                    "predicted_text": predicted_text,
                    "confidence_scores": {string.ascii_uppercase[i] if i < 26 else str(i - 26): percentage
                                          for i, percentage in enumerate(confidence_percentages)},
                    "top_predictions": [
                        {
                            "class": string.ascii_uppercase[i] if i < 26 else str(i - 26),
                            "confidence": percentage
                        }
                        for i, percentage in enumerate(confidence_percentages)
                    ],
                }
                return predicted_text, debug_info
            else:
                return predicted_text, None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ocr_model = OCRModel(num_classes=36)
    trainer = OCRHandler(ocr_model)
    train_data_path = Path("dataset/text_identification/train")
    trainer.train(train_data_path, num_epochs=50, batch_size=32, learning_rate=0.001)
    test_data_path = Path("dataset/text_identification/test")
    trainer.test(train_data_path)
```

While I'm trying to test my OCR, in recognizing the character "0", it comes up with G? It makes no sense to me how something, that has been trained couple of a hundred of images comes up with G.

```
{'predicted_text': 'G', 'confidence_scores': {'A': 2.5511952117085457, 'B': 2.9084114357829094, 'C': 2.9245806857943535, 'D': 3.019385412335396, 'E': 2.867276221513748, 'F': 2.7050500735640526, 'G': 3.0951984226703644, 'H': 3.0260657891631126, 'I': 2.691103331744671, 'J': 2.631979249417782, 'K': 2.5525128468871117, 'L': 2.7190934866666794, 'M': 2.6693686842918396, 'N': 2.9030684381723404, 'O': 2.5663597509264946, 'P': 2.941553108394146, 'Q': 2.8950219973921776, 'R': 2.789396792650223, 'S': 2.6342585682868958, 'T': 2.5583021342754364, 'U': 2.799813263118267, 'V': 2.574686147272587, 'W': 2.713942527770996, 'X': 2.824728935956955, 'Y': 2.85495538264513, 'Z': 2.7191564440727234, '0': 2.6622315868735313, '1': 2.6157714426517487, '2': 2.8603684157133102, '3': 2.5942767038941383, '4': 2.733685076236725, '5': 2.891615778207779, '6': 3.0571456998586655, '7': 2.551230974495411, '8': 2.9105449095368385, '9': 2.986663021147251}, 'top_predictions': [{'class': 'A', 'confidence': 2.5511952117085457}, {'class': 'B', 'confidence': 2.9084114357829094}, {'class': 'C', 'confidence': 2.9245806857943535}, {'class': 'D', 'confidence': 3.019385412335396}, {'class': 'E', 'confidence': 2.867276221513748}, {'class': 'F', 'confidence': 2.7050500735640526}, {'class': 'G', 'confidence': 3.0951984226703644}, {'class': 'H', 'confidence': 3.0260657891631126}, {'class': 'I', 'confidence': 2.691103331744671}, {'class': 'J', 'confidence': 2.631979249417782}, {'class': 'K', 'confidence': 2.5525128468871117}, {'class': 'L', 'confidence': 2.7190934866666794}, {'class': 'M', 'confidence': 2.6693686842918396}, {'class': 'N', 'confidence': 2.9030684381723404}, {'class': 'O', 'confidence': 2.5663597509264946}, {'class': 'P', 'confidence': 2.941553108394146}, {'class': 'Q', 'confidence': 2.8950219973921776}, {'class': 'R', 'confidence': 2.789396792650223}, {'class': 'S', 'confidence': 2.6342585682868958}, {'class': 'T', 'confidence': 2.5583021342754364}, {'class': 'U', 'confidence': 2.799813263118267}, {'class': 'V', 'confidence': 2.574686147272587}, {'class': 'W', 'confidence': 2.713942527770996}, {'class': 'X', 'confidence': 2.824728935956955}, {'class': 'Y', 'confidence': 2.85495538264513}, {'class': 'Z', 'confidence': 2.7191564440727234}, {'class': '0', 'confidence': 2.6622315868735313}, {'class': '1', 'confidence': 2.6157714426517487}, {'class': '2', 'confidence': 2.8603684157133102}, {'class': '3', 'confidence': 2.5942767038941383}, {'class': '4', 'confidence': 2.733685076236725}, {'class': '5', 'confidence': 2.891615778207779}, {'class': '6', 'confidence': 3.0571456998586655}, {'class': '7', 'confidence': 2.551230974495411}, {'class': '8', 'confidence': 2.9105449095368385}, {'class': '9', 'confidence': 2.986663021147251}]}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've overfit.

Comment: @JJFord3 how can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139980/prevention-of-overfitting-in-convolutional-layers-of-a-cnn

Answer (score 1):

**There are a bunch of things here.**

> [The model] produces different predictions during training and
> testing phases.

From what you shared, this is a statement you can not possibly make. What I can see from your evaluation is that your loss is Loss: 0.0140 (if that is the accuracy metric that leaves you with 98.6 % accuracy and during testing you even rise to 99.69 %. So your model performs even better on test than on training data from what we can see here.

> During training, the model seems to perform really well, unimaginably
> well, achieving high accuracy on the training dataset. However, when I
> use the model to predict text from images during testing, the results
> are inconsistent.

Talking about inconsistent results, I would propose two things here.

a) **Define a validation set** which you are running on after each epoch, to really see inconsistencies
b) **Increase the size of your test set**. The smaller your test set, the higher the variance of the resulting accuracy (or whatever metric you are using). Judging from above your test set is way too small and might mislead you.
c) While you are at it, create **validation sets for each character**, so you get an idea about class-wise losses and really understand where the weaknesses of your model are.

These validation and testing routines, will then in a next step enable you to **improve your model by** adding data samples in underperforming classes, or weighing the loss of these classes higher during training. But first you need to make sure to get a clear picture.

> The confidence scores for each class also seem to fluctuate
> significantly, leading to unexpected predictions.

Confidences is another misleading term here. While this might reflect the probability with which a class is predicted, when you are having two similar classes within your set of classes, these will always influence each other and thus have shared and lower probabilities (e.g. G and 0 or O and 0).
To see what I mean you could **plot a heat map**, showing the averaged probabilities for each character with respect to the full set. So while confidence and probabilities are a good indicator they are heavily dependent on the similarity to other classes in the set.

> While I'm trying to test my OCR, in recognizing the character "0", it
> comes up with G?

Yes, as said - similar classes, makes the prediction task harder. And again sometimes it is really hard to distinguish a 0 from a G - depending on the writing. In case you better want to understand the issue at hand, it is always a good idea to **plot some samples**. Especially if it is handwritten characters there are semantic gaps, where without context, you will not be able to reach 100 % prediction accuracy.

> I'm not sure what to do now, I have minimal knowledge in neural
> networks.

I would do the things proposed in my answer (I marked them bold). The key message is "**Validate & Test**". You need to understand what is really happening when you predict. A few samples are not sufficient for that, so ramp up that game. Then it will be way easier to improve your model and take it from there.